# How can i get the rotated image in file

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

as of now i can upload my image in the database the problem is when i rotate the image.
the uploaded image is not the rotated one, its still the image that i upload that i didnt rotate.

how can i upload the rotated image ?

```
Stream FileStream = File.OpenRead(ServerPath + Filename);
       // Stream FileStream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
       // System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ServerPath + Filename);
        //System.Drawing.Bitmap postedimage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(FileStream);

        objImage = ScaleImage(PostedImage, 73);
        if (FileType != "jpg" && FileType != "JPG")
        {
            objImage.Save(ServerPath + jpgFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        else
        {
            //objImage.Save(ServerPath + Filename);
        }

        img = new byte[FileStream.Length];
        contentlength = FileStream.Length;

        if (contentlength > 506000)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "ClosePopup", "File is to large! Maximum size is 8kb", true);
        }

        else if (contentlength <= 506000)
        {
            //ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            //byte[] bytestr = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(objImage, typeof(byte[]));
            //fs.InputStream.Read(img, 0, fs.ContentLength);
            byte[] bytestr = null;
            var fsm = ToStream(objImage, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //Stream fsm = ScaleImage(objImage, 73);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsm);
            bytestr = br.ReadBytes((int)fsm.Length);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM tblphotoupload where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'", connection);

            SqlDataReader alinan_veri3;
            alinan_veri3 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (alinan_veri3.Read())
            {
                int sct = 2;
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(alinan_veri3["upload_count"]);

                if (sct == 2)
                {
                    if (a >= 2) a = 2;
                    sql = "update tblphotoupload set mem_photo" + Convert.ToString(a + 1) + " = @img, upload_date" + Convert.ToString(a + 1) + " = '" + sDateTime + "', mem_contenttype" + Convert.ToString(a + 1) + " = '" + FileType + "', mem_photofile" + Convert.ToString(a + 1) + " = '" + Filename + "', upload_count='" + (a + 1) + "' where mem_cardno = '" + sParameter + "'";
                    connection.Close();
                    SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EKConn"].ConnectionString);
                    connection2.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection2);
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", bytestr));
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection2.Close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //string ole;
                sql = "insert into tblphotoupload (mem_cardno, mem_photo1, upload_date1, upload_count, mem_contenttype1, mem_photofile1) values ('" + sParameter + "', @img, '" + sDateTime + "','1','" + FileType + "','" + Filename + "')";
                connection.Close();
                SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EKConn"].ConnectionString);
                connection2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql, connection2);
                cmd2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@img", bytestr));
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: At what point do you rotate the image?

Comment: @grovesNL i just need to get the rotated image at any point  :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to rotate it 90 degrees? 180? 270?

Comment: I agree with @grovesNL. YOu don't say when you rotate the image. If you rotate it on you local machine, ensure you save it to the local disk before uploading it to your database. I hope you don't expect changes to the image on you machine to be reflected automatically in the database!

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your file is saved on the disk and then save the file into DB.

If this will not help you probably will have to either:

- rotate it properly, rotation might be saved only by the image viewer without changing the image on the disk, i have encountered the issue with Picassa
- rotate it in the code (rotate bytes)